# Where should a .NET Web Application store it's (non database) setting

Tags: asp.net, .net, inno-setup

I am building a Web Application that will be installed many times. The application needs to be able to save certain setting itself upon request.

I have an installer (InnoSetup) but I want to very careful about what permissions I give the Web Application.

- I can't use a database.
- A default install always leaves the web.config as read-only. (Most secure)
- The registry can be problematic.  Unless there is a set of keys a DotNet webapp can always write to by default (IIS_IUSR)...
- I was considering App_Data, but the default permissions are no longer useful and Inno-Setup can't easily fix it correctly: 
  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2005172

Security and Ease of Setup are both big issues..

I also don't want to make a mess of the machines I install to.

A **FAILED** solution was to write to the user portion of the registry:

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\MyCo\\MyApp\\");
var reg = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\MyCo\\MyApp", true);
reg.SetValue("MyValue", (string)dataString, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String);
```

But I found out that writing to HKEY_CURRENT_USER is also not allowed by default on Server 2012 and likely others.  The server error page is helpful and gives options such as explicitly giving the IUSR_{MachineName} explicit permission but this is a no go for me.

So my final solution is to have the installer create a user configurable folder and then assigning all users Read/Write access to that folder.  The administrator can always lock it down more if they want.

If anyone has a better option then let me know.

Comment: Couldnt you just put it in the web.config appSettings section and use System.Configuration to read it?

Comment: That assumes that the app has permission to write to it's web.config.  That is not guaranteed and not normally considered safe.

Comment: So you are fetching this value from somewhere after the installer is ran and then saving it? If not, you could just preload the setting in the config

Comment: After the installer is ran.   And then irregularly for the life of the app.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but wouldn't giving the app permissions to write the system's registries be less secure than just modifying it's web.config? In your case an attacker can affect the entire system while when using web.config he can only affect your app.

Comment: @VAndrei, Actually in the example I am writing to the [CurrentUser] or HKCU portion of the registry.  That should not affect the stability of the system at all.

Comment: I'm curious. What kind of web application is installed on many computers, but doesn't use a database? At the very least they'd have to have some kind of web server running which in itself would require some level of security.

Comment: @Nick, an application that needs to know a few user configurable things before it can connect to its database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With InnoSetup I created a new Wizard page to suggest and collect a Data folder from the user.  The installer then:

- Created that folder and gave All Users Read/Write access,
- Added a HKLM registry key telling the Web App where to look for the folder,
- Notified the user that they should lock the folder down further to prevent abuse.